# How to solve a starting position problem?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote this code in Unity3D that should rotate an object in a circle, that's the case except that the starting position is not taken into account. 
I do not understand why the function written in start is not taken into account for the position

```
public class RotationCircuit : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timeCounter = 0;

    float speed;
    float width;
    float height;

    private float startPosY;
    private float startPosX;
    private float startPosZ;

    void Start()
    {
        speed = 1;
        width = 4; //largueur
        //height = 1; //hauteur

        startPosX = transform.position.x;
        startPosY = transform.position.y;
        startPosZ = transform.position.z;

        float y = GetComponent<Transform>().position.y;
        float x = GetComponent<Transform>().position.x;
        float z2 = GetComponent<Transform>().position.z;

        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z2);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        timeCounter += Time.deltaTime * speed;

        float x2 = Mathf.Cos(timeCounter) * width;
        //float y2 = Mathf.Sin(timeCounter) * height; //utile pour faire des haut et bas
        float y2 = GetComponent<Transform>().position.y;
        float z2 = GetComponent<Transform>().position.z;

        transform.position = new Vector3(x2, y2, z2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in general you should use `transform.position` instead of `GetComponent<Transform>().position`

---

Then your code block

```
float y = transform.position.y;
float x = transform.position.x;
float z2 = transform.position.z;

transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z2);
```

does change absolutely nothing ... you get the current position, store it in local variables and write back exactly the same position ...

Btw they also have the same values you already stored in

```
startPosX = transform.position.x;
startPosY = transform.position.y;
startPosZ = transform.position.z;
```

later you never use those values at any point.

The same thing in `Update`

```
float x2 = Mathf.Cos(timeCounter) * width;

float y2 = transform.position.y;
float z2 = transform.position.z;

transform.position = new Vector3(x2, y2, z2);
```

only changes the `x` component of the position which is calculated by

```
Mathf.Cos(timeCounter) * width;
```

which doesn't take the initial `transform.position.x` or `startPosX` into account at any point.

---

I don't exactly know how you want to take the start position into account but it looks like it would be something like this:

```
// Little hint: By making those fields serialized
// you can adjust those values directly in the Inspector
// especially while running the Game without having to recompile everytime
[SerializedField] private float speed = 1;
[SerializedField] private float width = 4;
[SerializedField] private float height = 1;

private float timeCounter = 0;
private Vector3 startPosition;

private void Start()
{
    // you can simply store the Vector3 position
    // no need to store each component individually
    startPosition = transform.position;
}

private void Update()
{
    timeCounter += Time.deltaTime * speed;

    var x = Mathf.Cos(timeCounter) * width;
    var y = Mathf.Sin(timeCounter) * height;

    //           from the startPosition    move x right          and y up
    transform.position = startPosition + Vector3.right * x + Vector3.up * y;
}
```

---

That the object in the beginning jumps once namely `width` to the right is obviously related to the `Mathf.Cos` which is `1` for the start time `0`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @derHugo, actually some functions like ```startPosition = transform.position;``` and ```Vector3.right * x```  are simpler and easier to use !